# How to add dynamic input name to db using mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I have a form which creates dynamic inputs with names like:

```
name="phoneDefault1"
name="phoneDefault2"
name="phoneDefault3"
name="phoneDefault4"

etc..
```

I want to add them to a model schema under the "addedNumbers" array which looks like this:

```
var contactSchema = new mongoose.Schema ({
name: String,
surname: String,
address: String,
email: String,
addedNumbers: [
    { phone: String,
    number: [Number],
    default: [Boolean] }
]
});
```

This is my attempt to add them to db using a for loop and adding them dynamically:

```
//create
app.post("/", function(req, res) {
    var phoneType = "";
    var phoneNumber = "";
    var phoneDefault = "";
    var numbers = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
        phoneType = req.body.phoneType[i];
        phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber[i];
        phoneDefault = req.body.phoneDefault[i];
        var number = {"phone": phoneType, "number": phoneNumber, "default": phoneDefault};
        numbers[i].push(number);
    }
    var name = req.body.name;
    var surname = req.body.surname;
    var address = req.body.address;
    var email = req.body.email;


var info = {name: name, surname: surname, address: address, emaiL: email};
Contact.create(info, function(err, createdContact){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/new");
    } else {
        for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
            createdContact.addedNumbers[i].push(numbers);
        }
        console.log(createdContact);
        console.log(numbers);
        res.redirect("/");
    }
 });
});
```

But the numbers arary stays empty and when I try to console.log(phoneType) it is also empty.

The goal is that the addedNumbers array looks like this :

```
addedNumbers: [
  {Number1},
  {Number2},
  {Number3}
]
etc..
```

Thank you

Comment: It's shows `null` because you are dealing with asynchronous functions; you are pushing the lists  and the `Contact` model save event happens before the push.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you enter the first for loop the numbers array is empty so it's length is 0 - therefore the loop will never execute

Edit:
in the first loop you probably want to say something like i < req.body.phoneNumber.length - I assume that it is the array you are sending in a form. There is also another mistake the numbers is not an array of arrays so you should not use:

```
numbers[i].push(number);
```

so the corrected code will be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < req.body.phoneNumber.length; i++) {
    phoneType = req.body.phoneType[i];
    phoneNumber = req.body.phoneNumber[i];
    phoneDefault = req.body.phoneDefault[i];
    var number = {"phone": phoneType, "number": phoneNumber, "default": phoneDefault};
    numbers.push(number);
```

Again the for loop when you are creating new object should be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
     createdContact.addedNumbers.push(numbers);
}
```

In the end you should save the object:

```
createdContact.save(function(err) {
    // handle error
    res.redirect("/");
});
```

Comment: I edited it as "i < numbers.length +1" but it keeps loading until it crashes

Comment: after you added that line I suspect that the numbers array will just keep growing. Also the line numbers[i].push() is incorrect because numbers[i] is not an array (it will actually be undefined). I'll try to edit my answer with proper code. Any additional info would help(for example what are the objects you are sending?)

Comment: CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "favicon.ico" at path "_id" for model "Contact" - this is the error I get when trying with the updated code..
And the i < req.body.phoneNumber.length; doesnt work because its an input and I have multiple of these

Comment: Again what are the objects you are sending? how the data looks like? try instead of adding the numbers after creating the object - adding them in info object

Comment: Looks like I fiddled with it more and it seems to work now, thank you very much!